# Nginx proxy_reverse for docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, curl, reverse-proxy

I am currently trying to deploy my app backend as Docker container with exposed ports to my root server.

If I am trying to curl the backend with `http://example.com:3000` I get an timeout,
if I try it through nginx (view config underneath) I get an empty response (`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`).

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  client_max_body_size 50m;
  ssl_certificate ... # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key ... # managed by Certbot

  location /backend/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/; 
  }
}
```

However if I try to curl it from the server itself I have no problems.

Here is the relevant output of the `docker ps` command:

```
COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                     NAMES
"node dist/server.js"    9 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes            0.0.0.0:9100->3000/tcp    backend
```

Curl expected (works when running on root server):

`$ curl http://localhost:3000`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You nginx is running ssl (port 443), so your curl should be:

`curl -i https://example.com/backend/`.

*dont specify any backend port*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was iptables on my server. Some rules were deleted resulting in a violated Docker configuration.

A simple `sudo service docker stop` was the trick.